# how to continue one test off another in jest to reduce repetitive code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Using jest to test a React component functionality, and there is a lot of repetitive code. I want to test a chain of events with an assertion at each step of the way. The following is psuedo code that is greatly simplified to focus on the problem at hand...

The below code is testing the chain of events. Clicking each 'colored-button' opens some dialog box. and the button at the bottom of the page changes to a different 'colored-button'

```
beforeEach(() => render(<TestComponent/>))

it('should do stuff', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('red-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('red-box').toBeTruthy())
  })

  it('should do stuff', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('red-button').click()
    screen.getByTestId('blue-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('blue-box').toBeTruthy())
  })

  it('should do stuff', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('red-button').click()
    screen.getByTestId('blue-button').click()
    screen.getByTestId('brown-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('brown-box').toBeTruthy())
  })

  it('should do stuff', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('red-button').click()
    screen.getByTestId('blue-button').click()
    screen.getByTestId('brown-button').click()
    screen.getByTestId('black-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('black-box').toBeTruthy())
  })
```

You can see how repetitive this is. However this solution below isn't optimal:

```
  beforeEach(() => render(<TestComponent/>))

  it('should do stuff', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('red-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('red-box').toBeTruthy())

    screen.getByTestId('blue-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('blue-box').toBeTruthy())

    screen.getByTestId('brown-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('brown-box').toBeTruthy())

    screen.getByTestId('black-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('black-box').toBeTruthy())
  })
```

There are 4 assertions for the single test, which goes against standards for testing. And its reduced to one `it` statement. where as the previous version describes each scenario, telling developers each thing that is being tested, which is a huge benefit of testing....

Is repetitive code something we have to deal with when testing? How do you best deal with this?

**Cypress testing doesn't have this problem because you can have `it` statements that continue from the last.** For example, if the following would be possible in jest, then it would be the best:

```
it('should show red box', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('red-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('red-box').toBeTruthy())
  })

  it('should show blue box', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('blue-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('blue-box').toBeTruthy())
  })

  it('should show brown box', async () => {
    screen.getByTestId('brown-button').click()
    expect(screen.getByTestId('brown-box').toBeTruthy())
  })
```

Comment: What if you just removed `beforeEach(() => render(<TestComponent/>))` and render it once? Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't that keep the changes you make from other `it`s because you're not re-rendering the component each test case